# Yarn struggling to build CSS

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg

I have a big project that runs in debug mode on IIS, with webpack and yarn.
Beside the big dimensions of js files (i am working on it), when I modify a CSS or a LESS file, yarn takes minutes to build a particular reference (it tells me '2/8 modules', etc.).

Can I find in some way what is causing the problem? Could be the dimensions of CSS and LESS files?

Comment: are you breaking down your output to chunks? I see a lot of impact on the build size of it. Besides, it can be the size of you css - especially if you have plenty of it and you use css plugin to pull it out to a separate file.

Comment: I'll try to optimize CSS, thanks, i will update this thread if i find a solution